# Condition on multiple columns and change the values using R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, na

I simplified the dataset to demonstrate what I want to do. I'm not used to dealing with multiple columns. Here I made a simple `data`

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 title_1=c(65,58,47,NA,25,27,43),
                 title_2=c(NA,NA,32,35,12,NA,1))
```

In my actual dataset there are so many columns, but for now I just named as above. My goal is to change the values of `title_1` and `title_2` by the following rule. If there is a number , change it to 1. If there is an NA value, change it to 0. But in my actual dataset, there are hundreds of columns named as `title_1, title_2, ... , title_100, ...` So, I cannot type all the column names. So for my simple `data`, I want to use the code that doesn't type the column names explicitly. My expected output is

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                       title_1=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1),
                       title_2=c(0,0,1,1,1,0,1))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With dplyr we can use tidyselect syntax inside `across()` to select all variables starting with `"title_"` and then apply a function on all selected columns inside `across()`:

```r
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 title_1=c(65,58,47,NA,25,27,43),
                 title_2=c(NA,NA,32,35,12,NA,1))

library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(across(starts_with("title_"), ~ ifelse(is.na(.x), 0, 1)))
#>   id title_1 title_2
#> 1  1       1       0
#> 2  1       1       0
#> 3  1       1       1
#> 4  2       0       1
#> 5  2       1       1
#> 6  2       1       0
#> 7  2       1       1
```

In base R we would use `grepl` to select the column names, then assign those columns new values with `lapply`:

```r
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
                 title_1=c(65,58,47,NA,25,27,43),
                 title_2=c(NA,NA,32,35,12,NA,1))

mycols <- grepl("^title_", names(data))

data[mycols] <- lapply(data[mycols], \(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, 1))
data

#>   id title_1 title_2
#> 1  1       1       0
#> 2  1       1       0
#> 3  1       1       1
#> 4  2       0       1
#> 5  2       1       1
#> 6  2       1       0
#> 7  2       1       1
```

Finally, we would select the columns with `data.table` similary, but here we'd prefer the actual names with `grep(value = TRUE)`:

```r
mycols <- grep("^title_", names(data), value = TRUE)

library(data.table)

data_tb <- as.data.table(data)

data_tb[,
        get("mycols") := lapply(.SD, \(x) ifelse(is.na(x), 0, 1)),
       .SDcols = mycols]

data_tb
#>    id title_1 title_2
#> 1:  1       1       0
#> 2:  1       1       0
#> 3:  1       1       1
#> 4:  2       0       1
#> 5:  2       1       1
#> 6:  2       1       0
#> 7:  2       1       1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

While an `ifelse` statement as presented by @TimTeaFan is the best solution,
here is an alternative approach using `across` twice:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(across(-id, ~ .-.+1),
         across(-id, ~ replace_na(.,0)))
```

```
  id title_1 title_2
1  1       1       0
2  1       1       0
3  1       1       1
4  2       0       1
5  2       1       1
6  2       1       0
7  2       1       1
```